# Python-Sqlite3: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to use sqltie3 to store the `y` value which is the number of capture events that have happened. However when I go to create the new folder using `os.mkdir()` i am getting the error

`OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'Captures\\Capevent<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00000283DBAB1CE0>'`

I am not sure what is causing this because I believe that I have set everything up correctly. Any help would be great.

My Python Code(The Relevant Parts)

```py
#SQLITE DATABASE SETUP
iter = sqlite3.connect('iterations.db')
i = iter.cursor()
# i.execute("""CREATE TABLE iterations (
#         numiterations integer
#         )""")

# iter.commit()

global y
y = i.execute("SELECT * FROM iterations WHERE numiterations")

#SQLITE FUNCTIONS
def add_iterations():
    with iter:
        i.execute("UPDATE iterations SET numiterations =:last", {'last': y})
        print(i.fetchone())

# IMAGE CAPTURE FUNCTION
def imgcap():
    cv2.startWindowThread()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    framerate = cap.get(10)
    x=1
    dirname = 'Captures\\Capevent' + str(y)
    os.mkdir(dirname)
```

Comment: This is tagged with both py2.7 and py3.x, is this what you're actually using?

Comment: I am using 3.7, but I think it would work with both

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've interpreted your code correctly, you want:

```
dirname = 'Captures\\Capevent' + str(y.fetchone()[0])
```

to fetch the result of the query from the cursor.

Comment: I tried your code, and got the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment`. Not sure what caused that?

Comment: You replaced the original `dirname` assignment, right? Doesn't your original code use `y` in the exact same spot?

Comment: I did replace the original `dirname` assignment. dirname is only assigned once in my code

Comment: I have tried a few other things, still isn't working @SuperStormer